# Linq select latest in group hierarchy

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to get the latest record for each group if records when self-referencing hierarchy exists.

My table looks like this:

```
RecordId CreatedDate ParentRecordId
   1     2012/05/13       NULL   
   2     2012/05/13       NULL   
   3     2012/05/14        1     
   4     2012/05/15        3
```

I want to select only latest versions of records.
So in this case I only want to select RecordId = 2 and RecordId =4.

Here's what I have so far and I'm stuck.

```
     db.Records
       .Where(x => x.ParentRecordId!= null).GroupBy(x => x.ParentRecordId)
       .SelectMany(x=>x.OrderByDescending(y=>y.CreatedDate).Take(1)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My left joins are a bit lacking, but something like this ought to do it;

```
var query = from r1 in db.Records
            join r2 in db.Records
                on r1.RecordId equals r2.ParentRecordId into rec
            from r in rec.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where r == null
            select r1;
```

Comment: Awesome, this works fine, but how do I make sure that the record is the latest in the group? Do I just have to add orderbydescending?

Comment: @user194076 It gives you record 2 and 4, the last records in their respective group (records that have not been replaced with a new record, ie there's no record with them as parentid) No need to sort unless you want 2 and 4 in a specific order.

Answer (score 1):

How about a query that answers "Get all entries for which there is not another entry that considers me a parent".   That sounds like the same thing, unless I misunderstand:

```
db.Records.Where(x => !db.Records
    .Select(r => r.ParentRecordId).Contains(x.RecordId))
```

However, I'm a little confused on what you mean by "circularity".  How can a hierarchy be circular?

Comment: OP wants only latest versions of records that's there is a group by and Take 1

Comment: `However, I'm a little confused on what you mean by "circularity". How can a hierarchy be circular?`  A hierarchy, by it's very definition, cannot be circular.  However, a self referential table may not be a hierarchy.  You could have item 1 be the parent of item 2, and item 2 be the parent of item 1.  That would be a cycle, thus making it no longer a valid hierarchy.

Comment: I'm confused on what the OP wants, as I think his code would be correct for 1 interpretation.  Maybe if he updates with an example of how his current code isn't working I will understand the problem better.

Answer (score 1):

you should get a list of the `ParentRecordId`s first, and then check to see if the `RecordId` is in that list, if it is then we should exclude it from the results:

```
var parentIds = db.Records
                .Where(r => r.ParentRecordId != null)
                .Select(r => r.ParentRecordId)
                // this ToList call may increase performance. Depending 
                // on the size of the result set we may not want to call
                // the database every time for this info
                .ToList();
var wantedRecords = from r in db.Records
                    where !parentIds.Contains(r.RecordId)
                    select r;
```

Comment: Should work, just be aware that if you have millions of records in the database, it will fetch all of their parentid's just to pass them all back for a second `IN` query.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson that is a valid concern. However unless there are that many records, which would cause the memory used by this c# code to be a concern. I believe that the two separate queries will generally execute more quickly than the single query with the generated `IN` statement. However on Sql Server 2012 and above, that may no longer be the truth since it has performance enhancements for dynamic queries that previous versions do not.